# Creating table graph in R with plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I'm trying to create a dashboard using plotly API. Is there a way to plot a data table with plotly using R which I can merge with the dashboard. I can see a table option in python API https://plot.ly/python/table/ but the same feature is tough to find in R

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do it in R. You'll have add to annotations.

Answer (score 1):

I was having issues with the type='table' using Plotly in R.  Installing the ropensci/plotly package version 4.7.1.9000 from github fixed the issue for me.  `plot_ly(df, type="table")`